# Calculate text size before creating a Bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I've a Bitmap I create on demand. 
This bitmap, is going to contain a Canvas with some text inside it.

As you can imagine, this Bitmap is going to have a fixed size **depending** on the lenght of the characters to write in canvas and **aswell** on the specified text size.

So for example:

I trigger the method like this:

```
createBitmapText("This is text", 25);
```

So now, how can I calculate the bitmap's size?

I've tried something like:

```
int width = text.lenght * textSize;
```

However, for small strings it seems to work, but on long strings, there's a big empty space.

Any tips?

This is my code ATM:

```
public void createBlabla(String text, int fontSize){
    int padding = 15;

    Bitmap largeWhiteBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(fontSize * text.length(), fontSize + padding, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(largeWhiteBitmap);

    canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
    paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawText(text, padding, fontSize, paint);


    ImageView imv = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imv.setImageBitmap(largeWhiteBitmap);
}
```

Using examples:

```
createBlabla("APP", 25);
```

Results in:

[image]

As you can see, it kinda looks nice.

Buut, second example:

```
createBlabla("LONGER", 25);
```

[image]

```
createBlabla("LONGEST TEXT EVAH", 25);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure the width of the text you entered in pixels and set the width of the bitmap accordingly

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
float textWidth = paint.measureText(text)
```